# Where can I get a free 64 Bit NTFS boot disk?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, boot

No, my pc doesn't allow me to auto boot from the recovery partition. So I need:

- a boot disk that supports ntfs
- one that has a command line so I can access my 64bit NTFS Windows 7 drive
- one that supports 64bit systems

Any ideas?

Comment: I made my question better.

Comment: Are you trying to repair your computer or what exactly? What do you mean "my pc doesn't allow me to auto boot from the recovery partition"? Have you tried repeatedly pressing F8 at startup to get to the advanced boot menu so you can access repair options?

Comment: I have tried all of that. There is no recovery. My particular installation only has normal mode, or some quick fix mode, that also stalls. I need a  boot disk that can get me onto the recovery drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can boot from a "16bit" bootdisk.  The bitness (if that exists) doesn't matter.

Just ask around for a Windows 7 setup DVD.  Any one will do.  You'll want to boot into setup and use the "Repair System" option.

**edit**
UBCD
http://www.ubcd4win.com/downloads.htm

Hiren's bootCD
http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd

Microsoft also has downloads of Windows PE, but it's only on Technet now :(

Comment: I dont have access to a Windows 7 cd. I just need something small, an ISO I can write to a cd, that will allow me to boot. my pc didn't come with emergency disks...

Comment: In that case, look up Hiren's BootCD.

Comment: Hiren is too big.

Comment: How can it be to big? What exactly is your problem? Your asking for something and unless we know the reason, its hard to provide you the correct answer, that you will understand.  Just download the Windows 7 iso I do believe Microsofts just gives that away, just get the correct iso for the version of Win7 installed, use the Windows 7 USB/DVD to burn it to a USB/DVD drive/disk.

Comment: @Ramhound: Valid questions.  Hiren's could be too advanced for him.

Comment: If its to advanced for him, then he should say that, it being to "big" makes no sense.

Comment: @Ramhound: It's not too advanced for me. I've used it before. My problem is time. I can't download 600mb, because it will take me a whole day. I need a small boot disk, that works. I also plan to put it on a 128 MB flash disk...

Comment: p.s. I got an command.com error on a boot disk, saying it can't boot, which is why I figured it might be because the machine i'm trying to fix is a 64bit system.

Answer (score 1):

You can make one on any Windows 7 64 bit system, go to the All Programs menu, then the Maintenance Folder, then select "Create System Repair Disc"

[image]

Comment: I can't get into Windows from the broken machine. But this is still quite useful...

Comment: Do you have access to another W7 64bit PC? They can probably be found on bittorrent also.